# Comparison result within the same table

Tags: sql

[image]

I have a table of employee details month on month.

I need to find the difference result between two consecutive months.
For e.g. I have employees 1,2,3 in the month of Feb'19 and employees 2,3,4,5 in the month of mar'19.

I want the result as 1,4,5

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also explain what the data type column is for `month`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select empid
from t
where month in ('Feb-19', 'Mar-19')
group by empid
having count(*) = 1;
```